# MacOS Notifications Not Working with Multi-Monitor after Monterey Update

Tags: mac, display, notifications

I upgraded my Mac to Monterey a handful of weeks back and ever since then my notifications are not showing on-screen. They are there if I swipe over, they just don't actually notify me.

What I've learned is that when I'm just on my laptop, the notifications appear just fine, but when I'm connected to my multi-monitor setup they do not work.

After learning this, I dug into Notifications & Focus these were my settings:

[image]

This is exactly what I want. When checking the "When mirroring or sharing the display", however, notifications came back. The problem is, I'm not mirroring nor sharing my display. I'm plugged into my multi-monitor setup. I want notifications when plugged in, but would prefer NOT to have notifications when I'm mirroring or sharing.

Any ideas?

Macbook Pro M1 - 2020
Leveraging Thunderbolt port and Startech gear to provide support for multi-monitor.

Comment: Good catch with those settings. Notifications have been driving me nuts since the update. Following for more answers

Comment: I also run an M1 2020 13" that only officially supports one external monitor. I'm using a Plugable *4K Plug and Display* which uses DisplayLink to present the second external monitor.

I believe that since the Mac's processor is responsible for drawing this additional display, the system thinks it is "presenting." This would explain why this setting is required.

Answer (score 2):

In case anyone else has this problem, the bottom checkbox in the Notifications & Focus preferences window "When mirroring or sharing the display" needs to be checked to allow notifications when using multiple screens.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://apple.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://apple.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/328021)

Comment: This is the correct answer. It worked perfect for me.